# Best way to make a UI for a text adventure in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, text

I am very new to python and trying to make a classic text adventure. Currently my basic game just plays in the command prompt. 
How would I go about making a simple UI that:

1. Prints the game text in a large black font on a white background
2. Has an entry box at the bottom which collects inputs that are to be
   interpretted. (Like the command prompt)

Essentially a UI similiar to Zork.
I tried using tkinter, but I ended up getting confused and incredibly inefficient. Also, if you're wondering, I'd prefer not to just use the command prompt as the text is quite small and difficult for me to read.

Here's the main game code if that helps:

```
from player import Player

#intro screen
def intro():
    print('Incarnation')
    print('''
    Welcome to Incarnation, please type an option:
    - Play
    - Load
    - Instructions
    - Credits
    - Quit
    ''')
    option = input('>').lower()
    if option == 'play':
        play()
    elif option == 'instructions':

        print("""
        Objective: The objective of the game is to complete the narrative by exploring
        the world, collecting items, defeating enemies and solving puzzles.
        You control your character by typing commands.
        Here are some essential commands, make sure to experiment! They are not case sensitive.
        N, S, E, W: Move your character in the cardinal directions
        I: Open your inventory
        H: Heal with an item in your inventory
        A *item*: Attack with an item. Replace *item* with the name of the item.
        T *NPC*: Talk to a present NPC. Repalce *NPC* with the name of the person.
        """)
    elif option == 'credits':
        print('made by Lilian Wang')
    elif option == 'load':
        pass
    elif option == 'quit':
        quit()
    else:
        print("That's not an option.")

player = Player()

# Possible player actions
def actions(action):
    if action == 'n':
        player.move_north()
    elif action == 's':
        player.move_south()
    elif action == 'e':
        player.move_east()
    elif action == 'w':
        player.move_west()
    elif 'heal' in str(action):
        player.heal(action)
    else:
        print("You can't do that.")
        player.previousLocation = player.location


# Main game function
def play():
    print(player.location.name)
    while player.gameover == False:
        if player.previousLocation != player.location:
            print(player.location.name)
        action = input(">")
        actions(action)

intro()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PyQt4`, good for beginning with GUI then you can port over to PyQt5 easily.
An Example of simpe Hello World Program:
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

```
def window():
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
   w = QtGui.QWidget()
   b = QtGui.QLabel(w)
   b.setText("Hello World!")
   w.setGeometry(100,100,200,50)
   b.move(50,20)
   w.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
   w.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

Output:

[image]

PyQt4 is the best module for GUI design and very easy to learn. A Sneak Peak of what i am making right now with PyQt4 recently:

[image]

You can start learning PyQt4 [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/index.htm)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm looks interesting, Ill check it out! How would I go about printing new text to the screen each time they enter a command?

Comment: I can't explain you right now. You can create buttons as option as it helps user just clicking instead of typing whole option. First you have to learn PyQt4 basics then you can get help through google for basic things. :)

Mark the answer correct if you like it.